# Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart, firebase-authentication

I am unable to verify the OTP sent to my mobile no. and it's also not being verified automatication. I am getting this error
I am able to receive the OTP but autoverification is not working and when I enter the OTP then I get error of Invalid verification id. What i am missing I don't know.

```
ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.
E/flutter (13877): #0      catchPlatformException
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/…/utils/exception.dart:20
E/flutter (13877): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
E/flutter (13877): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (13877): #3      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:160:20)
E/flutter (13877): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
E/flutter (13877): #5      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
E/flutter (13877): #6      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
E/flutter (13877): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13877): #9      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/…/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:395
E/flutter (13877): #10     FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential
package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:436
E/flutter (13877): #11     Auth.authlogin
package:Shiyats/providers/auth.dart:11
E/flutter (13877): #12     _PhoneAuthenticationState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:Shiyats/screens/phone.dart:277
E/flutter (13877): #13     _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:993
E/flutter (13877): #14     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:1111
E/flutter (13877): #15     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter (13877): #16     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter (13877): #17     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
```

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:Shiyats/components/loginclipper.dart';
import 'package:Shiyats/providers/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pin_put/pin_put.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class PhoneAuthentication extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/phone';
  @override
  _PhoneAuthenticationState createState() => _PhoneAuthenticationState();
}

class _PhoneAuthenticationState extends State<PhoneAuthentication> {
  BoxDecoration get _pinPutDecoration {
    return BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    );
  }

  int state = 1;
  String dropdownValue = '(+91)   India';
  PhoneAuthCredential credential;
  PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential;
  final _phonenumber = TextEditingController();
  final _phonenode = FocusNode();
  String code;
  String id;
  final key = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
    final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = FocusNode();
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Container(
        //padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        //margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        height: double.infinity,

        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.center,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [Colors.black54, Colors.black]),
        ),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ClipPath(
                clipper: LoginClipper(),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: h * 0.55,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Phone Authentication',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.copyWith(
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              fontFamily: 'Lato',
                            ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'To get Shia Updates Regularly',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.copyWith(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Lato',
                            ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 40,
                      ),
                      Image(
                        image: AssetImage('images/shiyats_logo_png.png'),
                        height: 100,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        state == 1
                            ? 'Enter Your Mobile Number'
                            : 'Enter The OTP sent to you',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1.copyWith(
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                              fontFamily: 'Lato',
                            ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        state == 1
                            ? 'We will send you a OTP Message'
                            : 'Check your inbox you would have received a OTP',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.copyWith(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              fontFamily: 'Lato',
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              DropdownButton<String>(
                value: dropdownValue,
                dropdownColor: Colors.black54,
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.expand_more_sharp,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                iconSize: 24,
                elevation: 16,
                underline: Container(
                  height: 1,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                onChanged: (String newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = newValue;
                  });
                },
                //isExpanded: true,
                items: [
                  '(+91)   India',
                  '(+61)    Australia',
                  '(+1)   Canada',
                  '(+86)    China',
                  '(+98)    Iran',
                  '(+964)   Iraq',
                  '(+972)   Israel',
                  '(+92)    Pakistan',
                  '(+966)   Saudi Arabia',
                  '(+971)   United Arab Emirates',
                ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
                child: TextField(
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  controller: _phonenumber,
                  focusNode: _phonenode,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Enter Your Mobile Number',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                    ),
                    focusColor: Colors.white,
                    hoverColor: Colors.white,
                    //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                    enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (state == 2)
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
              if (state == 2)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
                  child: PinPut(
                    key: key,
                    fieldsCount: 6,
                    validator: (val) {
                      if (val.length != 6) return 'Enter The OTP';
                    },
                    onSubmit: (String pin) {
                      setState(() {
                        code = pin;
                      });
                    },
                    textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
                    controller: _pinPutController,
                    submittedFieldDecoration: _pinPutDecoration.copyWith(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    selectedFieldDecoration: _pinPutDecoration,
                    followingFieldDecoration: _pinPutDecoration.copyWith(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      border: Border.all(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 12,
              ),
              if (state == 1)
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      state = 2;
                    });

                    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                      phoneNumber: '+91${_phonenumber.text}',
                      verificationCompleted:
                          (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
                        print('verification');
                        await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                            .authlogin(credential);
                      },
                      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
                        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
                          print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
                        }
                      },
                      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
                        print('entered');
                        setState(() {
                          id = verificationId;
                        });
                        print(id);
                      },
                      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
                      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
                        print('Time-out');
                      },
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text('Send OTP'),
                  //colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              if (state == 2)
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    print(id);
                    print(code);
                    phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                      verificationId: id,
                      smsCode: _pinPutController.text,
                    );

                    print(phoneAuthCredential.token);
                    await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                        .authlogin(phoneAuthCredential);
                  },
                  child: Text('Verify'),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    state = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  'back',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my authlogin function

```
  Future<void> authlogin(PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    notifyListeners();
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Ya, that's not useful

Comment: can you tell whats the id and code value printed before calling `PhoneAuthProvider.credential()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `catchError` method:

```
Future<void> authlogin(PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).catchError((e) async{setError(e.message);});
    notifyListeners();
    return null;
  }
```